# How to remove index custom element in 2 dimensional array with empty value Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Supposed I have 2 dimensional array in javascript and I want remove the empty element something like this [] in array, for example:

```
// like this
var newArray = [["test1", "test2"], ["test3", "test4"], []];

// or like this
var newArray= [["test1", "test2"], [], ["test3", "test4"]];
```

and my code so far

```
var newArray= [["test1", "test2"], ["test3", "test4"], []];
for(var loop = 0; loop < newArray.length; loop++){
        if (newArray[loop] === null){
            // remove this empty element
            newArray[loop].slice();
        }
    }
console.log(newArray);
```

And my output so far

```
[ [ 'test1', 'test2' ], [ 'test3', 'test4' ], [] ]
```

How to remove that empty element? and when I print to the console the result that I want must:

```
[ [ 'test1', 'test2' ], [ 'test3', 'test4' ] ]
```

Please help and thank you

Comment: `twoDArray = twoDArray.filter( array => array.length)`

Comment: I know this is not an exact duplicate, but the solution should work here as well

Comment: Iam new in javascript, Did you mean the code is something like:

var  twoDArray = newArray.filter( newArray => newArray.length); There is an error on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
array = array.filter(a => a && a.length !== 0);
```

`filter` is one of the standard array functions provided by JavaScript. It is a higher order function that takes a predicate function which it applies to each element in the array. In this case we have an array of arrays so `a` is an array.

Comment: Sorry I am new in javascript. what is a in my code? is it something like newArray = newArray.filter(newArray => newArray && newArray.length !== 0)

Comment: `var newArray= [["test1", "test2"], ["test3", "test4"], []];
newArray = newArray.filter(a => a && a.length !== 0);`

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha I added some extra information. `a` is the name of the parameter that represents each value in the array. Since it's an array of arrays it takes the value of each inner array in turn

Comment: Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha sure thing

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: @learner I just confused with notification in webstorm that is an error like symbol `=>` and notification in a with the message "variable a implicitly declared"

Comment: @MohamadHandyNugraha that doesn't make sense because it's not even a variable but a parameter declared by the function literal that I'm passing inline to filter. `a => a && a.length !== 0` is the function

Comment: Looks like @MohamadHandyNugraha has defined a variable called a somewhere.

Comment: @learner but it would be shadowed by the parameter.

Comment: agreed. Might be some other things causing the issues.

Comment: @learner yeah, webstorm tries to do so much sometimes it freaks out

Answer (score 2):

You can also use more basic **`splice`** method to delete the element of an array without leaving null or empty values.

You can use this code as:

```
var newArray = [["test1", "test2"], ["test3", "test4"], []];

for(var loop = 0; loop < newArray.length; loop++){
    var tempArray = newArray[loop];    

    // safely check if empty value is actually an array or not, if array then only use length property so it doesn't get undefined
    if (Array.isArray(tempArray) && (tempArray.length == 0)) {
        newArray.splice(loop, 1);
        --loop;   // decrease the loop value by 1 because original array has its length decreased by 1
    }
}

console.log(newArray);

// [["test1","test2"],["test3","test4"]]
```